# Unable to add shadow to UIImage in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, calayer

I have a UITableViewCell that is drawing an image in `drawContentView:` I would like to add a shadow to it, so I am using CALayers:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    AsyncCell *cell = (AsyncCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[AsyncCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary* obj = [facebookPhotosData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell updateCellInfo:obj];

    CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
    sublayer.contents = (id)cell.image.CGImage;
    sublayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
    sublayer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
    sublayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    sublayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
    sublayer.frame = CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, cell.image.size.width, cell.image.size.height);
    [cell.layer addSublayer:sublayer];

    return cell;
}
```

here is my drawContentView method, if I add sublayers here, they keep stacking up:

```
- (void) drawContentView:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    NSString* caption = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[info objectForKey:@"caption"]];
    NSString* text = [info stringForKey:@"text"];

    CGFloat widthr = self.frame.size.width - 70;

    [[UIColor grayColor] set];
    [text drawInRect:CGRectMake(63.0, 25.0, widthr, 20.0) withFont:system14 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];

    if (self.image) {
        UIImage *imageToDisplay;
        imageToDisplay = self.image;
        imageToDisplay = [self imageWithImage:imageToDisplay scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(imageToDisplay.size.width / 1.5, imageToDisplay.size.height / 1.5)];
        CGFloat width;
        CGFloat height;
        CGRect r;
        if (imageToDisplay.size.width < 310 && imageToDisplay.size.height > 290) {
            imageToDisplay = [self imageByCropping:imageToDisplay toRect:CGRectMake(0, 20, imageToDisplay.size.width, 250)];

        }
        else if (imageToDisplay.size.width > 310 && imageToDisplay.size.height < 20) {
            imageToDisplay = [self imageByCropping:imageToDisplay toRect:CGRectMake(30, 0, 290, 250)];
        }
        else {
            imageToDisplay = [self imageByCropping:imageToDisplay toRect:CGRectMake(30, 0, 290, 250)];

        }

        width = imageToDisplay.size.width;
        height = imageToDisplay.size.height;
        r = CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, width, height);

        [imageToDisplay drawInRect:r];

        CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
        sublayer.contents = (id)imageToDisplay.CGImage;
        sublayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
        sublayer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
        sublayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        sublayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
        sublayer.frame = CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, imageToDisplay.size.width, imageToDisplay.size.height);
        [self.layer addSublayer:sublayer];


        //Experimental shadow stuff with images
        /*CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
        layer = [CALayer layer];
        layer.bounds = CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, imageToDisplay.size.width, imageToDisplay.size.height);
        layer.position = CGPointMake(150, 140);
        layer.contents = (id)imageToDisplay.CGImage;    

        layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.70;

        [self.layer addSublayer:layer];

        [self bezierPathWithCurvedShadowForRect:layer.bounds];*/

        [[UIColor blackColor] set];
        [caption drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 270 , 298, 20.0) withFont:system14 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    }
}
```

When I put the code in this delegate method nothing happens. If I add it to drawContentView it draws the shadow, but keeps adding layers as I scroll, that is incorrect. Not sure how I can add a shadow to my images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description provided it's not really clear to me what is there in drawContentView method and when it is called, but the reason why the code you gave "keeps adding layers as you scroll" is that it indeed adds your sublayer to a cell every time tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called (and that happens really often while scrolling)

So, the first obvious fix is the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

     AsyncCell *cell = (AsyncCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[AsyncCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault                 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
        sublayer.contents = (id)cell.image.CGImage;
        sublayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
        sublayer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
        sublayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        sublayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
        sublayer.frame = CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, cell.image.size.width, cell.image.size.height);
        [cell.layer addSublayer:sublayer];
    }

    NSDictionary* obj = [facebookPhotosData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell updateCellInfo:obj];

    return cell;
}
```

So you need to draw a shadow only once, probably when a cell is created.
Personally I would rather have this piece of code in AsyncCell class.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the same results, the shadow doesn't appear. When I put it in drawContentView, it gets added multiple times. Updated original question.

Comment: Where is drawContentView called?

Comment: And is there any reason why you're using drawInRect rather than just setting cell.textLabel.text property? is this done for speeding up while scrolling?

Comment: Do you call drawContentView method in drawRect?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, now I see what's happening. Try moving all your code from drawContentView: to drawRect: method. This should solve the problem, because drawRect method is only called when setNeedsDisplay flag is set, not every time the user is scrolling.